# Django Basics: 4.5 Mappings... Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

forgive me but I am a complete newbie to Django and Python.

I am going through the 'Django Basics' tutorial (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/setup.html)

I have completed up to the 4.5 Mappings section, and here is my code, identical to the site's tutorial code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'tango_with_django_project_17.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')), # ADD THIS NEW TUPLE!
)
```

At the end I run my server at 127.0.0.1.8000 and get the error:

```
Page not found (404)

Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django_project.urls, Django tried these 
URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^rango/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

At first I had to import 'patterns' to stop a NameError, but now my page won't show up at all. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I'm using:
Django 1.8 (www.tangowithdjango.com uses 1.7, should I change to this?)

Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't read the rest of the section:

> Restart the Django development server and visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango`.